90s-2000s Home Invasion Movie
I am looking for an old movie (maybe 90s-early 2000s). Two teenage girls and an adult woman (mother of one of the girls) are held hostage in their own house by a group of men. The woman's husband is a doctor and he tries to help his wife treating one of the men over the phone. I remember a scene where the woman stabs one of the men in his neck with a needle. I hope someone knows the name of the movie. 

Marked as a duplicate since I'm fairly sure the movie is actually called 'Home Invasion' (Group of men taking mom and teenaged girls hostage, her doctor husband helps her treat one of them over the phone, and she stabs one of them with a needle). If it's not the right one, please let me know.

You might be thinking of Panic Room?  I'm not sure if it matches all of the details you mentioned, since it has been a while since I saw it.
